# removing Output cache in Index view on update in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm using output caching for some Index views because they contain a lot of data.
I want to keep it specific for every user. because the view can differ depending on the roles.

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "none", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client)]
    public ActionResult Index(string schooljaarparam) {
        return View(_db.Lesplaatsens.Where(l => l.Schooljaar.Sch_Schooljaar == schooljaarparam).OrderBy(q => q.Lpl_Gemeente).ThenBy(q => q.Lpl_Instelling).ToList());
    }
```

Now when someone creates a new item and returns to the Index view. How do I remove the cache of the Index page, so that the newly created item will show up in the list?

I thought this would be a common question but I did not find a solution yet.

I guess you need to use `HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem()`
but how do I find the route. And where can I see the current cached items in the debugger?

Comment: Are you putting this on your controller?

Comment: No, this is on my Index action.

Comment: Index action => So on your controller then?

Comment: not ON, but IN yes, where else would i put this? :)

Comment: Well you could put it on the view as well using @output cache stuff.

Comment: but i used attributes...

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I have not helped but have just asked questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove the cached item because it isn't there (ie you are not caching it on the server).

When you say `Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client`, the browser will cache the response and won't even send a new request to your server when the user asks for the same page unless the cache expires or the user specifically asks for the latest version by hitting F5.

Comment: the browser doesnt cache it really, I mean, the browser DOES cache it but still does a request to the server. the server then answers with a `304 Not Modified` which tells the browser to use his own cache. if the browser returns a 200 OK then the browser will download the page...

Comment: @Stefanvds I just tested again to make sure (I'm testing with ASP.NET MVC 2). The behaviour for `OutputCacheLocation.Client` is like I described in the answer.